# C# - QueuedTaskScheduler - threadCount vs maxConcurrencyLevel

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I see the below from `QueuedTaskScheduler.cs` [documentation](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/parallelextensionsextras-tour-7-additional-taskschedulers/), but its not very clear to me.

`threadCount` - The number of threads to create and use for processing work items.
`maxConcurrencyLevel` - The maximum degree of concurrency allowed for this scheduler's work.

Question - What is the difference between `threadCount` & `maxConcurrencyLevel`?

Comment: Where is that QueuedTaskScheduler?

Comment: Its one of the task scheduler from https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSFT.ParallelExtensionsExtras/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`threadCount` is a number of physically created threads for your tasks to be done with scheduler. This means that your application will create a bunch of threads with a given limit.

> *Thread control*. The priorities, fairness, and concurrency level control all apply when `QueuedTaskScheduler` is used on top of another `TaskScheduler` as well as when used with dedicated threads for the scheduler. However, `QueuedTaskScheduler` also provides very low-level control over the threads utilized by the scheduler when dedicated threads are requested.

`maxConcurrencyLevel` is a number of concurrently executing **tasks** in your scheduler. This means that your scheduler will process a limited number of tasks simultaneously.

> *Concurrency Levels*. In a large system, you may want to control how much parallelism is afforded to different parts of the system. With parallel loops and PLINQ queries, you can control this on a per-loop or per-query basis, but out-of-the-box there’s no way to control it across loops, and there’s no built-in way to control it for tasks. By scheduling all related work to a `TaskScheduler` that enforces a maximum concurrency level, that functionality is gained.

The numbers looks very similar, but they are somewhat different. The `threadCount` should be nearly equal to the number of cores on your application server, as this helps you to avoid the context switch overhead, in theory.

As for the `maxConcurrencyLevel`, this number could be either nearly equal to number of threads (or number of threads + 1) or it could be much larger than it, if your tasks are quite small, so the processors will do them quickly.

All in all, you should try different combinations and measure up your system performance.

Also you can see some examples on [related post on MSDN blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/09/9990424.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I am still not very clear on the term concurrency level.  If I am executing 20 different queries in parallel, then what control its concurrency? Do I need to add any lock statement in the code?

Comment: TPL will control the number of simultaneous tasks by itself, no locks from you are required for this - only if you need some synchronization

Comment: Thanks for the info .